# R Summing intersections of variables

Tags: r

Once again data transformation is alluding me. I've tried aggregate, xtab, the apply functions, gmodels::CrossTable all sorts but nothing seems to work.

I have a table with four columns eg A:D each a numeric binomial variable (0, 1).

eg:

```
x <- data.frame(A = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                B = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                C = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                D = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
```

I would like an output where the rows and columns are both the variables (A:D) and the values are the sum of intersections.

eg:

```
output <- data.frame(A = c(3, 1, 3, 2),
                     B = c(1, 3, 1, 1),
                     C = c(3, 1, 3, 2),
                     D = c(2, 1, 2, 3))
rownames(output) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

For example if there were 3 observations in column A then the intersection of A-A in the output would be 3.  If there was 1 of the A observations also in variable B then the intersection of A-B in the output table would show 1 as would the intersection B-A.

Hope that makes sense. Its really bugging me how to do it.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this from matrix algebra.

```
M = as.matrix(x)
t(M) %*% M
  A B C D
A 3 1 3 2
B 1 3 1 1
C 3 1 3 2
D 2 1 2 3
```

Comment: equivalent `crossprod(M)`